# How fix bad date in carbon now() with ->isoFormat(' d MMM Y ')

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

i have problem i laravel with carbon.

Carbon::now() works ok, but i need use  this code ->isoFormat(' d MMM Y ') for convert date to much user friendly format "6 nov 2019".

But after convert is return value with different date (day).

WHY? what is bad?

update:
and any idea how i can use it in multilanguage sites in laravel project?

example: user EN have 6 nov 2019 user CS have 6 lis 2019 //czech

->isoFormat(' d MMM Y ') // have bad date, but in cs write "6 lis 2019" ->format('d M Y') // have good date, but in cs lang use english "6 nov 2019"

```
     <?php
        use Carbon\Carbon;

        $datetime = Carbon::now();
        $newdate = $datetime->isoFormat(' d MMM Y ');

        echo $datetime;  // show 2019-11-06 13:35:49

        echo $newdate;   // show 3 nov 2019

       ?>
```

Comment: `$datetime->->format('d M Y');` will give you `06 Nov 2019`

Comment: You need to use `createFromFormat`. Try it

Answer (score 0):

How about `$newdate = $datetime->format('d M Y');`

Output is `06 Nov 2019`

Answer (score 0):

Carbon is just a class extending DateTime. 
Use DateTime! https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

when you `echo $datetime`, there is obviously a `__toString()` function in Carbon, which by the look of it defaults to the standard `Y-m-d H:i:s` format.

Nothing looks wrong except your format.

```
<?php

$datetime = new DateTime();
$newdate = $datetime->format(' d M Y ');

echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  // shows 2019-11-06 13:35:49

echo $newdate;   // shows 6 Nov 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use carbon `Carbon::createFromFormat` as below:

```
$formated_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y', Carbon::now());
echo $formated_date;
```